# How to create a video like this?

Tags: video, video-editor, after-effects, hardware, lighting

How do I create a video like [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZysIbXxtzFI)?

If I want to create such videos, I want to know

1. Type of instruments to be used(including camera, etc.)
2. Light settings
3. After effects
4. Software suggestions if any

Comment: Is there some particular part of the video you are looking to reproduce?  It is best to describe what you are trying to do with words in addition to a link anyway (in case the link goes dead) and there is so many different things you could be asking about in that video that it really needs more clarification.

Comment: Additionally, it is unclear what you are asking with the 4 points.  Any kind of camera could have been used as long as it has reasonably high speed modes for the few slowed down shots and after effects isn't even really needed for what they did there.

Comment: you'll also need lots of paint! and lots of dancers :)

Comment: The link no longer works, and without a description of what the video showed, this question has become useless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As currently stated, the answer is, you can't.  The only thing special about that video is that it is very well planned out and coordinated with lots of lighting making it almost certainly outside your budget to reproduce something similar.

The video work itself is all actually fairly basic.  Any camera with a decent dynamic range and sharpness could capture the level of detail, though protecting it from the powder is always a fun trick.  It would need a decently fast frame rate for the shots that are slowed down, but 60fps would probably be sufficient.  They are also using a dolly or steadicam for the smooth shots that track across the scene (from one side to the other).

Most of what you see is simply lighting as shot that is then color graded to give it that look.  The color grading and speed adjustment is very basic and even a fairly simple non-linear editor could achieve it.

The problem is that the shots depend entirely on the content actually being shot and the way it was lit.  There is a ton of light on that scene.  There are three or four massive sport stadium/construction site style light arrays in the background and more light (possibly reflectors) in the front.  They all need to be properly aimed and setup to put the light where it is needed and this is a complex and costly operation that is drastically beyond the scope of what can be answered in a simple question and answer.

Comment: There's a lot more in that scene then great lighting, consider the actors and extras, and how they were directed for blocking, timing, and expression. This is far more valuable to the viewer than lighting alone, it's the voice and look of expression.

Comment: @filzilla - agreed, the original question asked specifically about lighting and effects though.  Most of the visual look comes from how it was shot, the content was also very well organized, but that is more directing than cinematography.

Comment: @AJHenderson, you are correct and you did answer the question. I just think that it should be mentioned that putting a scene together like that has a lot more to it than the scope of the question: directors, actors, makeup, wardrobe... tools are not enough, it takes very skilled people. But you know that. Sorry to be a pain in the butt.

Comment: @filzilla - not a pain in the butt at all.  I'm glad you commented.  It's great information.  I was just letting you know why I didn't include it in my answer.  That wasn't supposed to be disparaging, just explaining why I didn't update my answer to include it.  I think it is a great comment to have on the answer.

Comment: hi AJhenderson, thank you for the tip, you have a very good history of answering on target, you have this gift of focus, and filtering to connect with the question. Something I can learn by following you.